# How to make a different Django Api Url path

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-2.0

Django 2.1, python 3.6, djangorestframework.

When I go to the following url, I can see my data (great!) `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cards/1` This is what I see on the api page -

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "card_title": "Hello"
    },
]
```

I want to be able to go to this url to get to the same data - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cards/title/Hello`

How can I update my views and urls to do that?

base url

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/cards/', include('cards.api.urls')),
]
```

cards.api.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CardListView.as_view()),
    path('<str:pk>/', CardDetailView.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

cards.api.views.py

```
class CardList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()

    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CardSerializer


class CardDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    #permisssion_classes = (UserPermission,) # set the permission class
    permission_classes = ()

    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CardSerializer
```

I tried adding this to the cards.api.urls.py `path('api/cards/title/<str:pk>/', CardDetail.as_view()),` , but it still is looking at the `id` variable instead of the `card_title` variable.

Comment: can you try again with change `path` to `url` like `url('api/cards/title/<str:pk>/'`. Import this from `from django.conf.urls import url`?

Comment: @Micah *" it still is looking at the id variable instead of the card_title variable"* What you mean by this? you've said `/api/cards/title/1` api is the new one..right?

Comment: I made a mistake and asked the wrong question. I want to hit `api/cards/title/hello` instead of `api//cards/title/1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would help you,

```
# base urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/', include('cards.api.urls')), # remove "cards/" from url
]
```

and 
create a new view class, **`CardTitleDetail`** as below and add **`lookup_field`** attribute

```
class CardTitleDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'card_title'
    permission_classes = ()
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CardSerializer
```

```
# cards.api.urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('cards/', CardListView.as_view()),  # add "cards/" to the url
    path('cards/<str:pk>/', CardDetailView.as_view()),  # add "cards/" to the url
    path('cards/title/<str:card_title>/', CardTitleDetail.as_view()),  # this is the new url
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

---

**NOTE**
The **`card_title`** attribute should be **`unique`** across the DB, else it will raise exception!!

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I made the mistake of asking the wrong question. I want to hit `/api/cards/title/hello` instead of `/api/cards/title/1`

Comment: @MicahPearce Updated the answer :) Hope it will solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add another url in your cards.api.urls.py file redirecting to the same api for the same response.

#### Add this to your urls.py file urlpatterns.

```
path('title/<str:pk>/', CardDetailView.as_view()),
```

Then try hitting this http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cards/title/1

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I made the mistake of asking the wrong question. I want to hit `/api/cards/title/hello` instead of `/api/cards/title/1`